# F-test for comparing the mean of two groups

Tags: statistics, probability, distribution, variance

What would be the procedure, in terms of F-test, if I would like to check if the mean of one group is greater than the other group (alternative hypothesis: $\mu_1 > \mu_2$)?

And also what would change for the opposite alternative hypothesis: $\mu_1 < \mu_2$?

I know how to do it with t-test but got confused for the F-test, especially in terms of how to differentiate between left-tail and right-tail in an F distribution.